# How to make the coroutine/s to start only once? and why the speed variable when changing it's value not affecting the speed at all?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

a bit long but both scripts are connected. I can remove the second bottom script if it's not needed.

In the Update I'm using two flags:

setting them back to false at lines 72 and 73 when RotateEnabled is true:

```
if (RotateEnabled)
            {
                isResettingRotation = false;
                isSmoothRotation = false;

                _rect.Rotate(0, RotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0);
            }
```

but then in the else it's starting the coroutine 2-3 times in a row even if the flag isSmoothRotation is true.

```
else
            {
                if (!isSmoothRotation)
                {
                    isSmoothRotation = true;
                    StartCoroutine(SmoothRotateToStartDirection());
                }
            }
```

The second problem is with this variable:

```
public float smoothRotationSpeed { get; set; } = 2f;
```

when I'm changing the smoothRotationSpeed value for example to 10 then when using a break point on this line the value is still 2 in line 111 in the method: ResetRotationCoroutine

```
rotationLerpTimer += Time.deltaTime * smoothRotationSpeed;
```

I'm changing the value of the smoothRotationSpeed variable in the inspector through another script.

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

namespace EasyFloatingText
{
    public enum ObjectType
    {
        Type3D,
        Type2D,
    }

    public class FloatingText : MonoBehaviour
    {
        private Text _text;
        private RectTransform _rect;
        private Vector2 _offsetPos = new Vector2(0, 30);
        private ObjectType _modelType = ObjectType.Type3D;

        public string TextValue
        {
            get { return _text.text; }
            set { _text.text = value; }
        }

        public Vector2 OffsetPos
        {
            get { return _offsetPos; }
            set { _offsetPos = value; }
        }

        public Transform Target { get; set; }
        public Camera Camera { get; set; }
        public ObjectType ModelType
        {
            get { return _modelType; }
            set { _modelType = value; }
        }

        public bool RotateEnabled { get; set; } = false;
        public float RotationSpeed { get; set; } = 10f; // Individual rotation speed for each target
        public float smoothRotationSpeed { get; set; } = 2f;

        private bool isResettingRotation = false;
        private bool isSmoothRotation = false;
        private Quaternion startRotation;
        private Quaternion targetRotation;
        private float rotationLerpTimer = 0.001f;

        private void Awake()
        {
            _text = GetComponent<Text>();
            _rect = GetComponent<RectTransform>();
        }

        private void Start()
        {
            _text.alignment = TextAnchor.MiddleCenter;
            startRotation = _rect.rotation;
            targetRotation = _rect.rotation;
        }

        private void Update()
        {
            if (Target == null || Camera == null) return;
            var worldToScreenPoint = RectTransformUtility.WorldToScreenPoint(Camera, CalculatePosition());
            var screenPos = worldToScreenPoint + OffsetPos;
            _rect.position = screenPos;

            if (RotateEnabled)
            {
                isResettingRotation = false;
                isSmoothRotation = false;

                _rect.Rotate(0, RotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0);
            }
            else
            {
                if (!isSmoothRotation)
                {
                    isSmoothRotation = true;
                    StartCoroutine(SmoothRotateToStartDirection());
                }
            }
        }

        private IEnumerator SmoothRotateToStartDirection()
        {
            if (RotateEnabled)
            {
                if (rotationLerpTimer < 1f)
                {
                    float rotationProgress = Mathf.SmoothStep(0f, 1f, rotationLerpTimer);
                    _rect.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(targetRotation, startRotation, rotationProgress);
                    rotationLerpTimer += Time.deltaTime * smoothRotationSpeed;
                }
            }
            else if (!isResettingRotation)
            {
                isResettingRotation = true;
                yield return StartCoroutine(ResetRotationCoroutine());
            }
        }

        private IEnumerator ResetRotationCoroutine()
        {
            rotationLerpTimer = 0.001f;

            while (rotationLerpTimer < 1f)
            {
                rotationLerpTimer += Time.deltaTime * smoothRotationSpeed;
                float rotationProgress = Mathf.SmoothStep(0f, 1f, rotationLerpTimer);
                _rect.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(targetRotation, startRotation, rotationProgress);
                yield return null;
            }

            ResetRotation();
        }

        private Vector3 CalculatePosition()
        {
            // Calculate target position based on ObjectType (Type3D or Type2D)
            // ...
            Vector3 targetPosition;
            if (ModelType == ObjectType.Type3D)
            {
                var targetCollider = Target.GetComponent<Collider>();

                if (targetCollider != null)
                {
                    targetPosition = Target.GetComponent<Collider>().bounds.center +
                                     (((Vector3.up * Target.GetComponent<Collider>().bounds.size.y) * 0.5f));
                }
                else
                {
                    Debug.Log("Gameobject未找到Collider");
                    targetPosition = Target.position;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                var targetCollider = Target.GetComponent<Collider2D>();
                if (targetCollider != null)
                {
                    targetPosition = targetCollider.bounds.center +
                                     (((Vector3.up * targetCollider.bounds.size.y) * 0.5f));
                }
                else
                {
                    Debug.Log("Gameobject未找到Collider2D");
                    targetPosition = Target.position;
                }
            }

            return targetPosition;
        }

        private void ResetRotation()
        {
            startRotation = _rect.rotation;
            targetRotation = _rect.rotation;
            rotationLerpTimer = 0.001f;
        }
    }
}
```

The second script if it's needed is where I also changing the smoothRotationSpeed value:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using EasyFloatingText;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Demo : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<GameObject> go;
    public Camera camera;
    public bool rotateAllTargets = false; // Global bool variable for controlling all targets
    public float globalRotationSpeed;
    public float smoothRotationSpeed = 2f; // Add this variable

    private List<FloatingText> targets = new List<FloatingText>();

    void Start()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            var creator = new FloatingCreator();
            var text = creator.Create();
            var ft = text.GetComponent<FloatingText>();
            ft.TextValue = i.ToString();
            ft.Target = go[i].transform;
            ft.Camera = camera;
            ft.RotateEnabled = rotateAllTargets; // Set RotateEnabled based on the global bool variable
            ft.RotationSpeed = globalRotationSpeed;
            ft.smoothRotationSpeed = smoothRotationSpeed; // Pass the smoothRotationSpeed variable to FloatingText
            targets.Add(ft);
        }
    }

    void Update()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < targets.Count; i++)
        {
            if (rotateAllTargets)
            {
                // Rotate all targets
                targets[i].RotateEnabled = true;
                targets[i].RotationSpeed = globalRotationSpeed;
            }
            else
            {
                targets[i].RotateEnabled = go[i].GetComponent<TargetComponent>().rotateEnabled;
                targets[i].RotationSpeed = go[i].GetComponent<TargetComponent>().rotationSpeed;
            }

            targets[i].smoothRotationSpeed = smoothRotationSpeed;
        }
    }
}
```